# Pairwise Independence of Families of Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-analysis

A quick question which I'm sure will be trivial to you:

Let $I$ be a non-empty index set and $X_I:=(X_i \ | \ i\in I)$ be a family of pairwise independent random variables (i.e. suppose that $X_i$ is independent of $X_j$ for any $i,j\in I$ with $i\neq j$).

Given a partition $I = I_1 \sqcup I_2$, does it hold that the families $X_{I_1} \,(\equiv (X_i)_{i\in I_1})$ and $X_{I_2}$ are independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Let $I_1=\{1\}$ and $I_2=\{2,3\}$, let $X_2$ and $X_3$ be iid with $P(X_2=\pm1)=1/2$ and let $X_1=X_2X_3$.